# C# UWP ScrollViewer changing HorizontalScrollBarVisibility

Tags: c#, scroll, uwp, scrollbar, scrollviewer

I have a scroll viewer defined as bellow:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="svMain" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">
```

When I change property HorizontalScrollBarVisibility in code behind:

```
svMain.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
```

scrollviewer scrolls to horizontal offset 0.

How to prevent this, and leave horizontal offset of scrollviewer as it was before this change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
svMain.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
```

I used:

```
svMain.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
```

And this fixed my issue.

Comment: Glad you have solved it, however there is still an open bounty on this question. Is there still an issue somewhere?

Comment: I just don't know how to end a bounty.

Answer (score 2):

Completely untested but maybe it can point you in the right direction.

```
public double offset = 0.0;
```

Save offset before you disable the scrollbar:

```
offset = svMain.HorizontalOffset;
svMain.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
```

Once disabled, add the offset value back to the scrollbar

```
svMain.ChangeView(offset, null, null, false);
```

Comment: But this will make flickering effect. I would like to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, below is the best shot you can go with:

XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="svMain" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" ViewChanged="svMain_ViewChanged">
```

Code-Behind:

```
double offset = 0.0;
private void Button_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  offset = GetScrollViewerOffsetProportion(svMain) ;
  svMain.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
}

public static void ScrollToProportion(ScrollViewer scrollViewer, double scrollViewerOffsetProportion)
{
  if (scrollViewer == null) return;
  var scrollViewerHorizontalOffset = scrollViewerOffsetProportion * scrollViewer.ScrollableWidth;
  var scrollViewerVerticalOffset = scrollViewerOffsetProportion * scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight;
  scrollViewer.ChangeView(scrollViewerHorizontalOffset, scrollViewerVerticalOffset, null);
}
public static double GetScrollViewerOffsetProportion(ScrollViewer scrollViewer)
{
  if (scrollViewer == null) return 0;

  var horizontalOffsetProportion = (scrollViewer.ScrollableWidth == 0) ? 0 : (scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset / scrollViewer.ScrollableWidth);
  var verticalOffsetProportion = (scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight == 0) ? 0 : (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset / scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight);

  var scrollViewerOffsetProportion = Math.Max(horizontalOffsetProportion, verticalOffsetProportion);
  return scrollViewerOffsetProportion;
}
private void svMain_ViewChanging(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangingEventArgs e)
{
    if (svMain.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility == ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden)
    {
        ScrollToProportion(svMain, offset);
    }
}
```